# How to guess the function by its values on the mesh?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, numerical-methods

How to guess the function by its values on the mesh? More precisely, I have the value of a function on some uniform mesh. If you plot the graph of this function by points, you get the following picture.
[image: Function plot]
 The picture quality is poor, but I have values at 11325 points on a uniform mesh. What are the ways to guess the analytical representation of this function?

My main idea is to find with some accuracy the first few coefficients of the Taylor series, to restore the exact values ​​of the coefficients and sum the series.

**Attempt number 1.** Approximate the function by the Lagrange interpolation polynomial on a uniform mesh. This attempt failed, because on a uniform mesh the Lagrange polynomial even for small degrees (about 10) became very different from the function and had huge coefficients.

**Attempt number 2.** The method of coordinate-wise descent for the coefficients of the interpolation polynomial. Failed, because the coefficients instantly slid into some local extremum.

**Attempt number 3.** Approximate the function by the Lagrange interpolation polynomial on the Chebyshev mesh. I managed to approximate my function with a polynomial of degree 30 with an error of about 0.01 in the C-norm, but the coefficients again turned out to be quite large and completely different from the Taylor coefficients.

I will be happy with any help or ideas! [Here is the values of the function](https://pastebin.com/kfJ35hS5).

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? To try to discover an efficiently computable approximation of this curve, or are you trying to reverse engineer a likely simple mathematical closed form?

Comment: @orlp, I'm trying to find the distribution of the spectrum of a sequence of matrices with increasing orders. For this, I numerically found the matrix's eigenvalues, sorted them and put them on a uniform grid. They converge to such a function. I would like to find this function.

Comment: Are there reasons why the graph should or might be symmetric with respect to $\,(0,4)\,$?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to fit a 10th order polynomial (or 30th order Chebyshev) to the data is usually not wise, you could be experiencing what is called "Runge's phenomenon".  Off of visual inspection, I'd guess that you have a function that is a cubic plus a linear term (like $f(x) = ax^3 + bx + c$) so perhaps trying a lower order polynomial (3rd, 4th, or 5th order) would work better.  If you have MATLAB, I'd use cftool(x,f(x)) and try fitting a lower order polynomial.

It is usually beneficial to have some sort of theory behind the fit, meaning if theory tells us we expect a polynomial, an inverse trig function, a hyperbolic trig function, etc., then these are the first types of fits we try.  If you know where your data is coming from, then theory may be the place to start if none of the cftool fits are satisfactory.